# using continue in a for loop: the order it produces

Tags: java, oop, loops, for-loop, continue

can someone explain the order of operations for this function, i can not understand the order it is producing:

```
    // output
    // Yuhu
    // Tata
    // Yuhu
    // Yuhu
    // 3

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (i >= 3) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Yuhu");
        if (i >= 1) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println("Tata");
    }
    System.out.println(i);

  }
}
```

why is it not Yuhu, Tata, Yuhu, Tata, 3?

Comment: This would be the perfect question to solve by stepping through the code with a debugger.

Answer (score 3):

First iteration: `i` is `0`:  `i >= 3` is `false`, so no `break`.  `"Yuhu"` is printed.  `i >= 1` is `false`, so no `continue`.  `"Tata"` is printed.

Second iteration: `i` is `1`: `i >= 3` is `false`, so no `break`.  `"Yuhu"` is printed.  `i >= 1` is `true`, so `continue` ends *this iteration only*.  `"Tata"` is not printed.

Third iteration: `i` is `2`: `i >= 3` is `false`, so no `break`.  `"Yuhu"` is printed.  `i >= 1` is `true`, so `continue` ends *this iteration only*.  `"Tata"` is not printed.

Fourth iteration: `i` is `3`: `i >= 3` is `true`, so `break` breaks out of the `for` loop, and the output statement after the `for` loop prints `3`.

Answer (score 0):

because it wont get to "Tata" more than once, it only gets there when `i=0`,
`continue` immediately begins the next iteration of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try adding more debug statements to figure it out...

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (i >= 3) {
        System.out.printf("breaking (i=%d)%n", i);
        break;
    }
    System.out.printf("Yuhu (i=%d)%n", i);
    if (i >= 1) {
        System.out.printf("continuing (i=%d)%n", i);
        continue;
    }
    System.out.printf("Tata (i=%d)%n", i);
}
System.out.println(i);
```

Prints:

```
Yuhu (i=0)
Tata (i=0)
Yuhu (i=1)
continuing (i=1)
Yuhu (i=2)
continuing (i=2)
breaking (i=3)
3
```